# Change Label BackColor to default

Tags: vba, userform

I was wondering how i can change the Background Color of a label in a UserForm back to the default value? (Transparent or like the UserFormcolor)

```
Info_Label.BackColor = xlTransparent
```

or

```
Info_Label.BackColor = xlNone
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the label to be transparent, you need to set the `BackStyle` property like so:

```
'Transparent
Info_Label.BackStyle = 0

'Opaque
Info_Label.BackStyle = 1
```

Alternatively, to return the label `BackColor` to the default color:

```
Info_Label.BackColor = vbButtonFace
```

Comment: thx very much, you were both at the same time. don't now which answer to accept xD

Answer (score 5):

The default colour is the enum value `vbButtonFace` so:

```
Info_Label.BackColor = vbButtonFace
```

Or to match the current form:

```
Info_Label.BackColor = me.BackColor
```

Comment: thx very much, you were both at the same time. don't now which answer to accept xD

Comment: Gareth mentioned transparency which is probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: i gave it to him, he is newer. maybe its a motivation ;)
thx anyway.